# Using after() to add some text after my logo in the header, but the text loads an additional time every time user goes to another page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a commercial Wordpress theme, and I would like to add some text next to the logo, but the theme has no default option to do so.

I am able to get it to work using

```
$('.q_logo').after('<div class="logo-addition"><h5>#1 CONCRETE</h5></div>');
```

But if I go from one page to another, the text is an loaded additional time. And if i go to another page, the text is loaded yet again.

As you can tell, I'm a newbie...

Comment: Why not just check `if($'(logo-addition).length == 0)` before append  ?

Comment: ^ Fixed: `if($('.logo-addition').length == 0)`

Comment: Do you mind sharing what the full code would be? Again - a big rookie here.